# SQL Query to fetch all the tasks where Level 0 is C but all the other levels(if any) are in W

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is a table containing the status of each level of a task.

```
   TaskID  Level  Status

    1       0     C
    1       1     W
    1       2     W
    2       0     C
    2       1     C
    3       0     C
    3       1     C
    3       2     W
    3       3     W
```

QUERY : I need to have a query that will Give me a list of all the tasks    where Level 0 is C but all the other levels(level > 0) have to be in the W Status.

```
According to the above data only Task 1 has to be the output.
Task 2 is invalid because its level 1 is completed.
Task 3 is invalid because one of its level > 0(Level 1) has a C Status.
```

What I have till now is the below but it's not working as required.

```
Select distinct t1.TaskID
from tasks_tbl t1 
inner join tasks_tbl t2
on t1.TaskID= t2.TaskID
where t1.level = 0 and t1.Status like 'C'
and t2.level > 0 and t2.status like 'W'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a simpler way, but this should give it to you:

```
SELECT TaskID
FROM tasks_tbl
GROUP BY TaskID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 0 AND Status = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
AND MAX(CASE WHEN Level > 0 AND Status <> 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast way

```
SELECT TaskID FROM tasks_tbl where  (Level = 0 AND Status = 'C') or ( Level > 0 AND Status <> 'W')
```